# Searching for phone numbers using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I've got a contacts table in my database with phone numbers that don't follow any particular format. For example, they could be in the format `+1 (800) 111-2222` or just `8001112222`.

I need to take an input phone number (e.g. from a registration form) and search my contacts table to see if that phone number already exists. Of course, the input phone number could also be in any format, with or without special characters. Therefore I need to strip all non-numerical characters from both the table value and the input value so that I can do a comparison. How do I go about doing this?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
string inputPhoneNumber = "+1 (800) 111-2222";
MyContact existing = context.MyContacts
    .Where(u => stripChars(u.Phone) == stripChars(inputPhoneNumber))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Where `stripChars()` is just a method name I came up with that strips all non-numerical characters from the given string.

**Update**: I've implemented my `stripChars()` method as follows:

```
public static string StripNonNumerical(string input)
{
    Regex numbers = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
    return numbers.Replace(input, "");
}
```

Is it OK for me to use this custom method inside a lambda expression?

Comment: @MongZhu Unfortunately they are not. I can't format them either because many phone numbers also contain an extension. Ideally the extension should've been in a separate column, but I don't have any control over that.

Comment: I just read the line " don't follow any particular format. " :) have you tried `Split()` and `Replace()` ? those are some candidates that are translatable

Comment: why don't just normalize them, for example, getting rid of all non numerical characters & spaces and since you are doing a `FirstOrDefault()`, that implies you expect to get first result, then move your lamba to the `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Is caching numbers (say in `HashSet<string>`) an option?

Comment: "could also be in any format", Well then there is no more game. Get your best regex ready there will be a format that defeat it. And no rules means that there will be no "Cannot. Triple-stamped it." when I comes with Zalgo like thai char.

Comment: `౬ \r\n+(೬൬ ૨) ୨ ௨ ౨๙ ໙ ９ ��` any issue with my dummy phone number? For now I only used real digit are we allowed "_with or without special characters_"

Comment: Btw [here](https://regex101.com/r/hbm9vP/1) you will find in blue the digit of the string. sadly the last question mark where not understand but they still are valid digit. And the C# proof https://dotnetfiddle.net/eSkXBe

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to strip all the input that's not a number from user input and do the same with the values you are searching and compare them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite that as:

```
MyContact existing = context.MyContacts
    .FirstOrDefault(u => stripChars(u.Phone) == stripChars(inputPhoneNumber));
```

of, if you just want to know whether it exists:

```
if (context.MyContacts
    .Any(u => stripChars(u.Phone) == stripChars(inputPhoneNumber))
```

Or were you asking for suggestions on the `stripChars()` function?

Comment: I've found a snippet of code that I can use for my `stripChars()` function, so I'm good there. However is it OK for me to use a custom method inside a lambda expression, or will it throw an exception?

Comment: " or will it throw an exception?" the fastest way to find this out is actually to try it... ;)

Comment: I think you can use any code that you could use outside the lambda (at least, I've not found an exception!) When I was learning them, I'd write a lambda as a `foreach` and an `if`, and then convert it.